# How do I use awk to generate variables which I can conduct calculations with?

Tags: bash, loops, csv, awk

I currently have the following code which prints out all of the values between row 2 and row 599 in column #4 of a .csv file called chimefrbcat1.csv.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F , 'NR >= 2 && NR <= 599 { print NR " " $4 }' chimefrbcat1.csv |
while read -r lineno chimera; do
  echo "chimera on line $lineno is $chimera"
done
```

However, I would like the code to work as the following:

1. Grabs the value in row 2 column #4 AND column #7
2. Generates two variables for each value which I can use for calculations
3. Moves on to row 3 and changes the values of the two variables

I am pretty sure I need a 'for-loop' with a `counter` variable which corresponds to the row line but I am not sure how to write it.

Comment: What would be wrong with `{ print NR " " $4 " " $7 }` and then `read -r lineno col4 col7` ?

Comment: if i had to add the values in the variables $col4 and $col7 ($col4 + $col7) where would I put it in?

Comment: It depends on where you want it. You can do it either in the `bash` loop or in the `awk` script.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that this is a good starting point for whatever you're planning to do afterwards. In particular "generate variables which I can conduct calculations with?" sounds like you're going to try to use a shell for something it isn't designed to do and you should instead be doing whatever calculations you need to do inside the same awk script that reads your input file. If you [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output (i.e. after those "calculations") then we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add column 4 and column 7 you can either do it in the `awk` script:

```
awk -F , 'NR >= 2 && NR <= 599 { print NR " " $4 " " $7 " " $4+$7 }' chimefrbcat1.csv |
while read -r lineno col4 col7 sum; do
    echo "line:$lineno  $col4  +  $col7  =  $sum"
done
```

or in `bash` using arithmetic expansion:

```
awk -F , 'NR >= 2 && NR <= 599 { print NR " " $4 " " $7 }' chimefrbcat1.csv |
while read -r lineno col4 col7; do
    ((sum = col4 + col7))
    echo "line:$lineno  $col4  +  $col7  =  $sum"
done
```